# custom post type - project link output via single-portfolio.php

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have the following code registering metabox with form input used to input live project link

```
    function portfolio_meta_box() {

  add_meta_box ('project-meta', 'Add Project Link', 'portfolio_meta_options',  'portfolio', 'side', 'low');

  }

  add_action("admin_init", "portfolio_meta_box");

  function portfolio_meta_options(){

        global $post;

        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $link = $custom ['project-link'][0];
  ?>

  <input name="project-link" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
  <?php
   }


//save custom meta boxes when the post is saved


function save_project_link (){

  global $post;

  if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )  {
     return $post_id;
  }

  else  {

    update_post_meta ($post->ID, 'project-link', $_POST['project-link']);
  }
}

add_action ('save_post', 'save_project_link');
```

In my single-portfolio.php I am using this code to output a project URL

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<main class="view"> 

   <?php $link= get_post_custom_values('project-link'); 
      if($link[0] != "") ://!= not equal empty string
    ?>                     
       <a href="<?=$link[0]?>" target="_blank">view site</a>

      <?php  else: ?>

      <em>live link unavailable</em>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php     while ( have_posts() ) :the_post(); the_content(); endwhile;?>

</main><!-- .site-main -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

which gives me the following output (see left column on the screenshot) but I was wondering how can I change the code to give me the output shown in right column (its a clickable link which should appear under the first project screenshot only)

[image]

My second question is I've noticed in `$link = $custom ['project-link'][0];` and

```
'<?php $link= get_post_custom_values('project-link'); 
      if($link[0] != "") ://!= not equal empty string
    ?>                     
       <a href="<?=$link[0]?>" target="_blank">view site</a>'
```

we use **['project-link'][0];**  and **$link[0]**. Is the first one ['project-link'][0];an indexed array with zero index which makes it pick the 1st value in the array? as to the second $link[0] why do we need zero index in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use Wordpress Code Reference to understand what is going on:

**get_post_custom()** is a function that retrieves post meta fields and needs a post id as an parameter. It returns an **array** with post meta for the given post:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/

**get_post_custom_values()** is a function that retrieves values for a custom post field and accepts the key and the post id as parameters. It returns an **array** of meta field values.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom_values/

So you need the indexes to access the first position in the arrays. If you want to take a look at the the indexes of the array, you can output them like:

```
$key_values = get_post_custom_values( 'project-link' );

echo $key_values[0];
```

This will show you what the array contains on index position 0. Try it with 1 or 2, if you want to see whats inside of these index positions.

---

The other question was, how you get the desired output. First of all you want to show the url, so you have to put it between the a tags:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link[0]; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $link[0]; ?></a>
```

And if you want to put it below your content, you need to put your **the_content()** call above the a tag. Also I guess you should use it inside your post loop and use the function get_post_custom_values with the post id:

```
<main class="view">
    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :the_post();
            the_content();
            $current_post = get_the_ID();
            $link= get_post_custom_values('project-link', $current_post); 
            if($link[0] != "") { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link[0]; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $link[0]; ?></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <em>live link unavailable</em>
            <?php }
        endwhile;
    ?>
</main><!-- .site-main -->
```

Hope this helps and I understood your question correctly.

Comment: foreach loop to output the whole array throws an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I edited my answer. You do not actualy need to do a for each, because you just want to check whats in [0]. But you can also output the other index positions. Is there the value you want to recieve?

Comment: I want to understand why we are using zero value and not 1, 2 or other value

Comment: And this is the reason, why you should look whats inside of it. This way you will find out, why you use the 0 index and if you like to, what the other values are. If it is not an array, you do not need a index number.

Comment: ok in other words because this array contains only one value which is website URL zero outputs this value, if I put 1 instead of 0 nothing happens.

Comment: Your modified loop code doesn't put URL where I want - I only want URL under first screenshot not below the whole post content. Please take a look at my question.

Comment: Is the first screenshot a image inserted in your content (the_content() ) ? If the answer is yes, then just paste the link in your content, no need to adjust the single page of posts. You get post content with the_content().

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all your help @rank